# Why is the software center not alphabetized?

Tags: software-center

Would be so much better if it were, especially for n00bies.

Answer (score 4):

There is an option there on the upper right corner of software center.

By Name

By Top Rated (Default)

By Newest First

You should change that by Name.

> 1. Open Software Center
> 2. Select Category (Accessories, Book & Magazines ... & etc).
> 3. List of Softwares will display.
> 4. On your upper right there is a selection box with the options above. Just select an option based on your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that it's better for beginners if it's categorized, not alphabetized.

If someone knows the name and wants to find it, all they need to do is type a few letters into the search box, and it will be located, which is easier than looking for it alphabetically.

I really don't see why it would be so much better if it were alphabetized; can you give a use case to illustrate why you think this?